# Can I create a ListView with values on the right and left hand side at the same time?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I'm trying to make a scoreboard with the players name (a string) on the left side and the player's score (an integer) on the right. Like this:

```
Player1       0
Player2       0
Player3       0
Player4       0
etc.
```

where the players are taken from an ArrayList of strings.

When the name of the player is tapped, the integer on the right should go up by one. I tried using a HashMap to do this, and the table displayed fine, but the HashMap has no ordering so I can't tell it which number to add one to. I also tried a LinkHashMap and had similar problems.
I figured using a ListView would be most convenient because each item in the list has a position. I was wondering if it's possible to create a ListView with strings on the left side and integers on the right, while being able to change the values of the integers on the right by tapping on the strings on the left. The integers don't have to be aligned to the right, but just positioned to the right side of the strings.
If you could also show the code that would make this possible, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

If there is another better solution to this, that would be helpful too.

Comment: You can use `ArrayAdapter<T>` where T is a class that holds string (left) and int (right)

Comment: @SargeBorsch Could you get into more detail on how to do that? I'm new to this so I'm not really sure what exactly it is I need to do.

Comment: I'm too lazy, but @SuppressWarnings's answer is talking about the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your HashMap in which the key is a hidden view in your listview rows. So you can retrieve the key easily when clicking on a row without having to show any extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a struct type of data for every player/score pair.

Then use an ArrayList< dataType > for the ArrayAdapter.

On the ArrayAdapter you can query and modify this values.

Comment: What would the datatype be in ArrayList< dataType> if I have both a string and an integer?

Comment: dataType is an object / class with 2 primitive type variable String and Integer.